# How to make difference between Android SDK method and my own method

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, getter

I'm trying to parse a JSON with GSON in an AsyncTask

The issue is : I have the method `android.os.AsyncTask.getStatus` and my own getter for my own class `Status` (this class is the parsing of my JSON file)

Can i set a nickname or something like this ?
How to make difference between Android SDK method and my own method ?

Comment: package name make the difference.

Comment: change it to a different name?

Comment: Just to expand on what Mengelle stated: `android.os.AsyncTask.getStatus()` will target that method. `my.package.name.and.class.getStatus()` will target your method

Comment: @Bonatti Can I set a "nickname" ? intead of `my.package.name.and.class.getStatus()` set : `class.getStatus()`

Comment: Yes. As far as Studio goes, you can writte the short as the local getStatus, and the full nominal one for the android.os one. The name lookup is always class first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Bonatti,

I can make the difference with full name :

`android.os.AsyncTask.getStatus()` will target that method.
`my.package.name.and.class.getStatus()` will target my method